# Mongoose how to use $elemMatch for nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have to used below Collection,

```
  {
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "modules": [
    {
      "name": "AAA",
      "group": [
        {
          "name": "g1",
          "ID":1
        },
        {
          "name": "g2",
          "ID":2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "BBB",
      "group": [
        {
          "name": "g3",
          "ID":3
        },
        {
          "name": "g4",
          "ID":4
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have to use below code,

```
test.find({'modules.group':{"$elemMatch":{'ID':1}}},{'modules.$.group': 1}).lean().exec(function(err, results) {

});
```

but the above code returns

```
"_id": ObjectId("..."),
"modules": [
    {
      "name": "AAA",
      "group": [
        {
          "name": "g1",
          "ID":1
        },
        {
          "name": "g2",
          "ID":2
        }
      ]
    }]
```

but i need only match Values array ID, I need below response,

```
"_id": ObjectId("..."),
"modules": [
    {
      "name": "AAA",
      "group": [
        {
          "name": "g1",
          "ID":1
        }
    }]
```

Please give some solution to solve this elementmatch problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it through [`aggregate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate), here are the sample codes.

```
test.aggregate()
     .unwind('modules')
     .project({
         "_id": 1,
         "modules": {
             "$filter": {
                  "input": "$modules.group",
                  "as": "elem",
                  "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$elem.ID", 1 ] }
             }
         }
     })
     .exec(function(err, ret){
     });
```

Comment: but i get undefined response

Comment: { [MongoError: exception: invalid operator '$filter']
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'exception: invalid operator \'$filter\'',
  errmsg: 'exception: invalid operator \'$filter\'',
  code: 15999,
  ok: 0 }

Comment: but i have same error..i think mongo version problem

Comment: @user2447562, `$filter` for mongodb 3.2